# What does this mean: MessageBox.Show((found ? "Password" : "Username") + " incorrect")?

Tags: c#

I am working on a login system and I have fully got it working. I got this piece of code from another website:

```
MessageBox.Show((found ? "Password" : "Username") + " incorrect")
```

But I am unsure to what it actually means and what it does.

Here is my full code:

```
 namespace frmSplashScreen
{
    public partial class frmLogin : Form
    {
        public frmLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        }

        int signUpPressed = 0;
        bool found = false;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string[] userdetails = File.ReadAllLines(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "UserDetails.txt");

            foreach (string user in userdetails)
            {
                string[] splitDetails = user.Split(':');
                Login.username = splitDetails[0];
                Login.password = splitDetails[1];

                if (txtUsername.Text == Login.username) 
                {
                    if (txtPassword.Text == Login.password)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Welcome " + Login.username);
                        this.Hide();
                        frmMainMenu menu = new frmMainMenu();
                        menu.Show();
                        return; // we're done here, so return instead of break
                    }
                    found = true;
                    break; // we're not gonna find this username again, so might as well quit the loop
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show((found ? "Password" : "Username") + " incorrect");
        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `? :` is a short way of saying `if (condition) ? true, return this : false, return this`. It's called the ternary operator, [see the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: That LoC = If the user was found show that the password was not correct. If the user was *not* found then the username must be incorrect.

Comment: @Equalsk Thanks, could you type it up as an answer so that I can close this thread, please?

Comment: I would, but it's clearly a duplicate and should be closed as such.

Comment: Sidenote: It is debateable if exposing "details" on failed logins to the end user makes sense. If you tell "Login incorrect" - they have to find a suitable pair of Username/PW - if you give Details what is wrong it is more customer friendly but also easier to spoof.

Comment: Hope that atleast the `:` is an illegal character in your usernames/passwords, but your login mechanism seems very primitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is short version of this code

```
var message = "";
if (found) {
  message = "Password "+ " incorrect";
} else {
  message = "Username "+ " incorrect";
}

MessageBox.Show(message)
```